# SQL - how to change the format of a current_timestamp to have 'mm ss' as zeros?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, timestamp

I want to check if a metric is still missing 4 hours later and return a single record if it exists. I wrote a query that checks if there were metrics in the last 4 hours. But I need to check if there is a metric for a certain hour that was expected to load 4 hours before.

```
-- Returns records that appeared within the last 4 hours

select * from main.basic_metrics
where metric_name = 'common_metric' 
and transaction_time > current_timestamp - interval 4 hours
```

The problem is that `transaction_time`is in the following format `2019-10-30T12:00:00.000+0000` where `mm ss` are always zeros. So when I check it like `transaction_time = current_timestamp - interval 4 hours` it returns nothing since `current_timestamp` contains `mm ss` data.

How should I format timestamp to the format similar to `transaction_time` - `2019-10-30T12:00:00.000+0000` ?

UPD: There was a typo, mentioned in the comments below. fixed it

Comment: The hours are not zero in your example. Which data type is `transaction_time`? Why is it not a `timestamp with time zone`?

Comment: @samba format 2019-10-30T12:00:00.000+0000 has hh and it is 12. Is this just an example of the format or your data is like this ?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sorry guys! That was a typo, I meant `mm ss` - everything after hh is zero. Will edit now

Comment: @samba can you please show us some data from the table basic_metrics (put it in the question)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should be very simple: cast the string to `timestamp with time zone`:

```
WHERE CAST(transaction_time AS timestamp with time zone)
      > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '4 hours'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select * from main.basic_metrics
where metric_name = 'common_metric' 
and transaction_time = date_trunc('hour',current_timestamp) - interval 4 hours
```

This is not necessarily the best query for what you're doing, but it does solve the problem you're having. My guess is that some version of "between" or > and < would solve it, however without knowing exactly how the "transaction time" is populated, I'm could only venture guesses.

The trick in my example is to "truncate" everything after the "hours" off of the current_timestamp using date_trunc()

Note: It helps a lot to realize that timestamps are NOT formatted. Timestamps are a single long integer field that happens to get formatted on your screen so you can make sense of it. Text comparisons are nearly always the wrong way to do things, and datetime aware functions are the preferred method of doing any comparison.